# How can I find the number of elements in an already declared array of size n, if it's partially filled?

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose I created an array of size 5. Filled two number 1 and 2 at index 0 and 1 respectively. Now I want to return number of elements currently present in the array, i.e. 2 and not 5 given by size below. How can I do that?

```
    int arr[5];
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    //size returns 5 but I want it to return 2, since it has only 2 elements.
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout << size;
```

Comment: It's not possible. You have to keep track of how many elements you put in yourself. That's why `std::vector` exists.

Comment: The simple way I can think is by using a loop and checking if the element is empty or not.

Comment: @RAZIUL Whats an `empty element`?

Comment: You have 5 elements present in there at all times. Some of them are uninitialized (or 0 if you intitialize the array differently), but they're still there.

Comment: @RAZIUL That will only work if all numbers are supposed to be not 0. And then you would need to initialize all values to 0 explicltly. e.g. unsigned int arr[5]{}; But using std::vector from #include <vector> is much more robust

Comment: yes, but sadly he is asking for Array

Comment: There is no such thing as a "partially filled array" in  C++.   An array has the same number of elements throughout its lifetime.  If your program deems that some elements in an array may be absent or not present, it needs to keep track.  One example is keeping track of the number of "used" elements (which will not exceed array size) and only access elements `0` to `n_used - 1`.   Another example is picking a value to represent an unused element (e.g. if all elements are `int`, and only positive integers are useful, specify that `-1` represents an unused element).

Comment: Or `std::optional<int> arr[5]` maybe? Be then, it is not an array of `int`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a classic array, it is not possible to do what you say, you will get 5 outputs each time. But if you use `std::vector`, the size of the vector will change automatically every time you add a new element to the vector. Then, you can easily count the number of elements in the vector by using the `size()` function. you can print to the screen.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) { vec.push_back(i); }
    std::cout << "number of elements= " << vec.size();
    return 0;
}
```